# Confused over initialisation of instance variables

Tags: java, scjp, ocpjp

I'm studying up for the SCJP exam, upon doing some mock tests I came across this one :

It asks what is the output of the following :

```
class TestClass
{
   int i = getInt();
   int k = 20;
   public int getInt() {  return k+1;  }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      TestClass t = new TestClass();
      System.out.println(t.i+"  "+t.k);
   }
}
```

I thought it would be `21 20`, since t.i would invoke getInt, which then increments k to make 21.

However, the answer is `1 20`. I don't understand why it would be 1, can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The variables are initialized from top to bottom.

This is what happens:

1. Initially both `i` and `k` have the (default) value `0`.
2. The value computed by `getInt()` (which at the time is `0 + 1`) is assigned to `i`
3. `20` is assigned to `k`
4. `1 20` is printed.

**Good reading:**

- [The Java™ Tutorials: Initializing Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: +1, when `i` is initialized, `k` still has the default value of `0`

Comment: @HotLicks - There's nothing static about this.

Comment: No, it's not handled by the constant pool. Check with `javap` yourself.

Comment: @HotLicks, I don't know why you say that. Adding `static` [doesn't really change anything](http://ideone.com/0VHoo). A tip; if you feel rusty, and you're not sure about the answer, either try it out using a compiler of your choice, or don't bother answering / commenting. In the end it will just be considered noise.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Are you saying the compiler does something against the spec if it prints `1 20`? Could you give a reference to the spec in that case? (btw, did you downvote me? if so, why?)

Comment: I'm talking about the JVM.  There are two ways to initialize a field -- *field initializers* and with executable statements in the <init> or <clinit> methods.  Field initializers can only init to a literal value, while the methods can basically do anything you can do with code.

Comment: @HotLicks - I for one am having trouble following you. What's your point? Nothing is being swizzled. And the downvote here is perplexing.

Answer (score 0):

jvm will follows like this,

1.identification for non-static members from top to bottom
2.executing non-static variables and blocks from top to bottom 
3.executing the constructor......

in the first step jvm will provide default values..on that time variables in readindirectly write only state..